# javascript only showing first 4 character from the output

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript. I have this output:
`a,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 11:52:12 2015@q,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 12:30:28 2015@r,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 12:36:11 2015`

I want to be able to show first four letter of the user id and the character before the last user id. Something like this: `rr73,rr73,rr73, r.`

The first output usually look like this:
`r,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 13:01:48 2015`
In this case i want the output to show `rr73, r`

I was want to be able to replace `@q` with a `?` mark:
`@q,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 12:30:28 2015`
In this case i want the output to show: `rr73, ?`.

I also want to be able to replace `@a` with `A`:
`@a,rr7323,Thu Jul 16 11:52:12 2015` should look like `rr73, A`.

Here is my code it's only showing the first 4 letters of the user id `rr73, rr73, rr73`

```
if (label == 'edit.history@status') {
    var names = [];
    var pieces = tag.split(",");
    // even number entries are the user:
    // r,mm5830,Mon some date@r,pk5982, Tues some date
    for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length;i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
        // and we only want first 4 characters
            names.push(pieces[i].substring(-2, 4));
        }
    }
tags[label] = names.join(",");
```

Comment: can you please format your code with what the test strings are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the substring command in JavaScript treats any negative number as 0, so your substring code is actually starting at 0, the first character, and proceeding for 4 characters.

You cannot refer to a negative substring as we only have the string. You previously broke the original string into pieces.

Because of this, you may need to add `pieces[i-1] +` in that `push()` to get it to work.

I believe the following should work as expected, except for the replacing of values. For that, you may need to use the `replace` function and further edit the string from `pieces[i-1]` that I added:

```
if (label == 'edit.history@status') {
var names = [];
var pieces = tag.split(",");
// even number entries are the user:
// r,mm5830,Mon some date@r,pk5982, Tues some date

var last = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length;i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        last = i;  // change the last index to be the current one.
        // and we only want first 4 characters
        names.push(pieces[i].substring(0, 4));
    }
}

var lastChar = pieces[last-1];
lastChar = lastChar.substring(lastChar.length-1);
if(lastChar == "q") {
  names.push("?");
} else if (lastChar == "a") {
  names.push("A");
} else {
  names.push(lastChar);
}

tags[label] = names.join(",");
```